# Adding a string into Delphi memoedit

Tags: delphi, memo

I want to add an string into specified place of a Memo Edit in delphi, how can I do this?
I mean I want to know where the mouse cursor is within TMemo, and then add a string to this position. Is that possible?

Comment: This is really very, very basic stuff you should be able to find on most tutorials. Something like MemoEdit1.Lines.Add('xxx') or MemoEdit1.Lines.Text:=MemoEdit1.Lines.Text+'xxx'. You should some more research before posting.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I think you miss understanding my question, of course I know using your help suggestion like memoEdit1.Lines.Add('XXX') or the other one, but the thing that I want to do is like this: Adding a string into a line, but not a specified line! but some where the mouse points, is it possible? could you help me? I can use OnMouseUp or OnMouseMove events too.

Comment: Then you should explain the problem better and provide examples of what you've tried.

Comment: Do you want to insert at the cursor position or the caret position? Please edit your question so that we know what you want.

Comment: Sounds like drag'n'drop

Comment: I want to insert at the cursor position.

Comment: Please edit the question, instead of using comments to add information not provided in the question itself. This may be helpful to others in the future... but not as is.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `EM_CHARFROMPOS` to determine the character position of where the mouse cursor points:

```
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  Pos: Integer;
begin
 Pt := Memo1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
 if (Pt.X >= 0) and (Pt.Y >= 0) then begin
   Pos := LoWord(Memo1.Perform(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, MakeLong(Pt.x, Pt.Y)));
   Memo1.SelLength := 0;
   Memo1.SelStart := Pos;
   Memo1.SelText := '.. insert here ..';
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to place your string at the caret position of your memo you can use the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.InsertStringAtcaret(MyMemo: TMemo; const MyString: string);
begin
  MyMemo.Text :=
  // copy the text before the caret
    Copy(MyMemo.Text, 1, MyMemo.SelStart) +
  // then add your string
    MyString +
  // and now ad the text from the memo that cames after the caret
  // Note: if you did have selected text, this text will be replaced, in other words, we copy here the text from the memo that cames after the selection
    Copy(MyMemo.Text, MyMemo.SelStart + MyMemo.SelLength + 1, length(MyMemo.Text));

  // clear text selection
  MyMemo.SelLength := 0;
  // set the caret after the inserted string
  MyMemo.SelStart := MyMemo.SelStart + length(MyString) + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Just `MyMemo.SelText := MyString` is enough. Possibly with `MyMemo.SelLength := 0` in front, depending on OP's wishes.

Comment: But it's not what you asked! You asked for mouse cursor position, not caret position. Sure, a mouse click at the mouse position will result in the "same" caret position, but why then not asking about the caret position?

Answer (score 0):

You can *add* a string to the bottom of the ".Lines" member: `MyMemo.Lines.add('MyString')`.

You can also *replace* a string in any (already existing) position in "Lines" you want: `MyMemo.Lines[2] := 'MyString'`.

Finally, you can *insert* anywhere you want: `MyMemo.Lines.Insert(2, 'MyString')`

Comment: tnx for your all replies.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple (NGLN's answer):

```
MyMemo.SelText := MyString;
```